# Migrate from Vue2 to Vue3

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vuejs3, webpack-5

I'm trying to migrate big project, about 2000 components and I have a lot of packages that not relevant in Vue3, 'Element-UI' for instace.

After upgrade Vue to version 3.1.0-0 and add @vue/compat version 3.1.0-0 and @vue/compiler-sfc version 3.1.0-0, I fix all errors and trying to 'npm run dev', than I saw this error

[image]

In addition, I have update vue-loader to version 16.0.0 and changed main.js to this:

[image]

My package.json:
[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: first line `import Vue, {createApp} from 'Vue'` change to `import { createApp } from 'vue'` .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Still.... same error

Comment: Images are forbidden here, please post those as actual (highlighted) text. Otherwise, you can follow the official guide: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/ Maybe upgrade towards the latest version of Vue too.

Answer (score 0):

This question ranks high in google, so I would add a settings for Vue 3. With Webpack 5 and Vue 3, the webpack config alias changes to this:

```
resolve: {
extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.vue' ],
alias: {
    'vue': '@vue/runtime-dom'
}
```

},

Alternatively this may be the solution, if the are transpilation errors:

```
  alias: {
    'Vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
}
```